# Undefined index in select form

Tags: php

When I click submit it gives me an error, "Undefined Index: selection" not sure why I thought I did everything correct, I made it similar to some of my other pages which connect to the DB just fine. Selection is in DB and I defined it in IF statement, could someone shed some possibly obvious light on my issue?

```
<form action="login_success.php" method="POST">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
        $selection = $_POST['selection']; 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (selection) VALUE ('$selection')");
    }   
?>

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Pick</legend>
        <select id="tm1" name="teams">
        <?php
        $tt = date("H");

        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '     <option value="wr"'.$dis.'>Washington Redskins</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="nyg"'.$dis.'>New York Giants</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="pe"'.$dis.'>Philadelphia Eagles</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="dc"'.$dis.'>Dallas Cowboys</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="br"'.$dis.'>Baltimore Ravens</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="ps"'.$dis.'>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="tt"'.$dis.'>Tennessee Titans</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="gbp"'.$dis.'>Green Bay Packers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="ss"'.$dis.'>Seattle Seahawks</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="cbr"'.$dis.'>Cleveland Browns</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="bb"'.$dis.'>Buffalo Bills</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="jj"'.$dis.'>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="ic"'.$dis.'>Indianapolis Colts</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="ht"'.$dis.'>Houston Texans</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="kcc"'.$dis.'>Kansas City Chiefs</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="md"'.$dis.'>Miami Dolphins</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="nep"'.$dis.'>New England Patriots</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="nyj"'.$dis.'>New York Jets</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="slr"'.$dis.'>Saint Louis Rams</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="nos"'.$dis.'>New Orleans Saints</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="mv"'.$dis.'>Minnesota Vikings</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="tbb"'.$dis.'>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="ac"'.$dis.'>Arizona Cardinals</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="af"'.$dis.'>Atlanta Falcons</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="sf49"'.$dis.'>San Francisco 49ers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="sdc"'.$dis.'>San Diego Chargers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="or"'.$dis.'>Oakland Raiders</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="db"'.$dis.'>Denver Broncos</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="cbe"'.$dis.'>Cincinnati Bengals</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="cp"'.$dis.'>Carolina Panthers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="dl"'.$dis.'>Detroit Lions</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="cbea"'.$dis.'>Chicago Bears</option>';
        ?>

        </select>
        <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitbtn">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `name="selection"` in your form????

Comment: There is an error, so everything is not correct. Namely exactly what the error says: there is no element with the name selection in your form.

Comment: thanks @Saty didnt even realize just a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the value of `$_POST['selection']` you are trying to access is not set, and due to that it's throwing `Notice: Undefined Index ...`

Answer (score 0):

`$selection = $_POST['selection'];`  should be `$selection = $_POST['teams'];`

**OR**

`<select id="tm1" name="teams">` should be `<select id="tm1" name="selection">`

In other words there should be a consistency between your form elements and  `$_POST` array indexes.